# What is the difference between .locals import * and import local

Tags: python, python-import, local

I am writing a code for flappy bird and I was watching a tutorial on collision and they used:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

Why don't they just use:

```
from pygame import local
```

What is the difference and how does it change the code? Does it import all of that library or just a specific bit. As I thought you would just use import pygame for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one imports everything from `pygame.locals`.  You can then
access elements of the `pygame.locals` without prefixing with the
module name.

```py
from pygame.locals import *
print(K_a)  # 97 = ascii code of 'a'
```

The second one imports the module `locals` from pygame.  You can
basically access the same things but now you have to use the module
name as a prefix.

```py
from pygame import locals
print(K_a)  # NameError: name 'K_a' is not defined
print(locals.K_a)  # 97 = ascii code of 'a'
```

The second form is preferable because then you do not have the risk of
hiding definitions in `pygame.locals` as below:

```py
from pygame.locals import *
K_a = 21  #  hide K_a from pygame.locals
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's understand it by a example

**I have Directory named myApp and inside it I have 2 files**

~app.py
~helper.py

**In helper.py my code is**

```
abc1 = 'hi'
abc2 = 'bye
```

**In app.py my code is**

```
from helper import *
print(abc1)
print(abc2)
```

So by use of `from helper import *` I can import all variables and functions from it but if I use `from helper import abc1` it only import abc1 value

Comment: What does the .locals do then is the same as just importing the locals or is there no difference?

Comment: ``from pygame.locals import *``
this code import all variables and functions from .local.py file

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, I get it now.